# How do I fix the RuntimeError in this program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This program is a function that takes dictionary and it must return a new dictionary with mirror image of the original dictionary (meaning key:value pairs are switched).

However, according to pythontutor.com, for the line of code that says the for loop, it throws a `RuntimeError`.

I am using the latest version of Python (3.4.1)

```
#Program purpose:               Write a function called rvBirthday that takes
#                               dictionary birthday as input. It returns a
#                               mirror image of the dictionary, where birthday
#                               is the key and name is the value.


def rvBirthday(birthday):
    reverseBD = {}
    for key in birthday.keys():
        date = birthday.get(key)
        birthday.pop(key)
        reverseBD[date] = key
    return reverseBD

birthday = {'Mitsuyuki Washida':'3-29-93', 'Joe Bob':'7-12-96',
        'Sam Wilson':'4-1-02'}
print(rvBirthday(birthday))
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in rvBirthday
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of extra work in that function that is not necessary. When iterating over a dictionary, don't call `.keys()`; you can just iterate over the dictionary itself. You already know all the keys are in the dictionary, so why use `.get()`? And why remove the key from the original dictionary? And besides, `.pop()` returns the value too, so you then don't need the `.get()` call.

Comment: @Andy: not if you pasted this into Python 3.4, as the OP stated they use. In Python 2 it'll work because `.keys()` creates a separate new list, but in Python 3 `.keys()` returns a dictionary view. To replicate the issue in Python 2 replace `.keys()` with `.viewkeys()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are altering the input dictionary *while looping over it* by using `dict.pop()`. This changes the dictionary size, and that breaks iteration.

Your instructions say nothing about removing keys from the input dictionary. Remove the `dict.pop()` calls altogether.

You don't need to use `.keys()` or `.get()` here either. Looping over a dictionary yields keys, so you don't have to use a separate method to extract the keys. You then know that those keys are in the dictionary, so `.get()` to return  default if it is missing is also redundant.

Better loop over the dictionary *items*; this gives you both the key and the value in one step:

```
def rvBirthday(birthday):
    reverseBD = {}
    for key, date in birthday.items():
        reverseBD[date] = key
    return reverseBD
```

This can be expressed with a dictionary comprehension too:

```
def rvBirthday(birthday):
    return {date: key for key, date in birthday.items()}
```

If you still need to clear the input dictionary, simply add a `birthday.clear()` call *after* copying across the key-value pairs.